# Send email from mailbox using .NET GraphServiceClient

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api

Scenario: Console application needs to send an email from defined mailbox. All setup in Azure is done and application has access and all works well in Postman.

Question is how to do the same with Microsoft libraries - especially with `GraphServiceClient`.

Note: example is not showing message body as it is not relevant for the question.

**Raw request**

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<email-address>/sendMail
```

**.NET code**

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, tenantId)
    .WithClientSecret(secret) 
    .Build();

ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

await graphClient.Me
    .SendMail(message, saveToSentItems)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this in c#.NET - here's some code, which has been refactored/simplified on the fly (so no guarantees) to just show what you need. Obviously you'll need to replace the magic strings with your own values.

```cs
var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async request =>
{
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/GUID");
    var credential = new ClientCredential("GUID", "P@55w0rd");
    var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/", credential);

    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
}));

var user = graphServiceClient.Users["from@example.com"];
var message = GetMailMessage(); // not relevant to question
await user.SendMail(message).Request().PostAsync(new CancellationTokenSource(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30)).Token);
```

Comment: Key for me was to realize that the `graphServiceClient.Users[email]` gives me the same options as `graphServiceClient.Me`